# Word for elements of a matrix whose main diagonal symmetric element is zero

Tags: matrices

What would you call the nonzero element $a_{ij}$ of a matrix $A$ whose 'transposed' element (i.e. the element $a_{ji}$, located symmetrically opposite $a_{ij}$ in the matrix across the main diagonal) is zero?

Alternatively, what name might you give to them as a pair $(a_{ij}, a_{ji})$ to reflect this relationship?

I originally thought of 'nilpotent' element however it feels like a misuse of the term as I'm not talking about "elements of a nilpotent matrix", but rather the nonzero element ($a_{ij}$) of a matrix ($A$) whose corresponding 'transposed' [cross-diagonal symmetry] element is zero ($a_{ji} = 0$), where $A$ is not a nilpotent matrix.

I'd think perhaps 'nilsymmetric', or 'annihilating' but these brought up very few search results and I'm wondering if there's a more accurate term.

**Edit** the context is a matrix multiplication, and I wish to emphasise that the presence of this zero will cause a term to disappear when multiplied by zero. I already have annotated antisymmetric (i.e. opposite signed) and symmetric (i.e. identical) elements, but couldn't think of a proper term to use for those I describe here.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the transpose of a matrix is zero, then the matrix must itself be zero. So, what do you mean by "matrix elements whose transpose is zero"? If you are in fact just talking about the zero matrix, then why would you need this term?

Comment: No I mean the symmetric counterpart of the element is zero, as I meant to communicate by reference to the coordinates ij vs. ji. I didn't mean $A^T = 0$ or a zero matrix. The "whose" in the title of this question refers to "elements" not "matrix"!

Comment: All right. It's not standard to use the term "the transpose of $a_{ij}$" to mean the element $a_{ji}$. However, there is not a common term for the relationship between these terms either.

Comment: I strongly object to the term "nilpotent elements", since I don't see any connection to the idea of nilpotency.

Comment: I think a term like "unpaired" makes a bit more sense, as in, "we say that the element $a_{ij}$ of $A$ is **unpaired** if the "transposed" entry $a_{ji}$ is zero".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're correct, my apologies I will edit my question with the right notation!

Comment: I would go for something like "The entries at the zero-pattern of $A^T$"